# Dualboot Ubuntu (13.04) + Windows 8 in EFI mode. Can't see dualboot screen (screen completely black) or BIOS screen, among other problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I recently attempted to dualboot Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows 8 in EFI mode on a Lenovo Ideapad U510. The installation went unhitched, but after restarting, I ran into a couple of problems.

1) The laptop screen will not display anything upon bootup, including the dualboot screen, BIOS, etc. As of this moment, I can boot into Ubuntu just by hitting enter blindly, but I have not been able to boot into Windows 8.

2) The laptop screen remains blank when Ubuntu has fully loaded. Interestingly, it will display everything expected on a second, much larger, external monitor. This essentially renders the portability of a laptop moot.

3) The laptop has an inability to connect to some secured Wi-Fi networks, despite authentication being correct. Attempts to connect are met with the authentication window popping up in regular intervals.

At the moment, I would appreciate it if people could help me fix my problem of not seeing anything upon powering up and entering the invisible boot screen. I would like to keep the dualboot, as I like Ubuntu for its ease of use for developing, but would also like tips as to how to uninstall this dualboot and return to Windows 8, worst comes to worst.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

The second problem might just be screen brightness.  I have the same device.  On startup it shows the ubuntu boot screen for a moment and then suddenly goes black.  But its just the brightness which is somehow initialized to its lowest level, and lowest level means black on this device.

I put the following line in \etc\rc.local, right before `exit 0`.

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Now the lights go off and immediately on again.